Разбор CSS единицы на число
Описание
В моей странице есть стандартный размер, заданный через стили css. Находится он в :root и имеет имя --size-standard. Я точно знаю что он есть, но не знаю какое у него единица измерения (px, cm, in, vw, vmin...).
В скрипте JS мне нужно получить это значение как число и использовать его для иных целей (к примеру для ширины линии в canvas-е).
Говоря "значение как число" имеется ввиду значение в пикселях конвертированный в число.
Проблема
Вот только что бы я не пробовал, мне не удается получить это значение в пикселях.
К примеру вот:


const stringSizeStandard = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(`--size-standard`);
const numberSizeStandard = CSSNumericValue.parse(stringSizeStandard).to(`px`).value;
:root {
  --size-standard: 6vmin;
}



Получаю:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'to' on 'CSSNumericValue': Cannot convert to px

Вопрос
Что я могу делать? Как мне разобрать CSS единицу на число?
Уточнение
Варианты без использования библиотек предпочтительнее.

разобрать не проблема - достаточно регулярок вместо CSSNumericValue.parse - который не поддерживается Firefox. Число - stringSizeStandard.match(/[\d]+/g), единицы измерения - stringSizeStandard.match(/[^\d]+/g). А вот перевод в px, да еще и с неопределенной исходной единицей измерения - нетривиальная задача, по-моему, только ручками в зависимости от особенностей полученной единицей измерения.

@Arbery я вот почему вцепился за этот CSSNumericValue.parse? Пока что отпустим поддержку для Firefox. Эта функция не только делает разбор и определяет нужные нам данные, но и конвертирует. К примеру, из cm в px не проблема. Так же и для много других единиц, но почему-то она выдает ошибку для vmin. Она не может конвертировать эту единицу ни во что. И честно сказать я пока не понимаю почему.

@Arbery можно предполагать что стили не загрузились и размер экрана нестабилен, но я так же проверял ее в DOMContentLoaded. И все же вышла ошибка.

а вот что это за конвертируемые cm? приложите линейку к экрану - точно ли 37.77px - это 1cm? Это слишком непростая задача - оцените весь зоопарк размеров - em, rem, vw, vh, %... - точно ли мощностей устройства хватит определить для каждого все параметры и правильно перевести? Даже если и есть какие-то намеки, то не в полной мере реализовано. Не могу на 100% с уверенностью ответить, но по-моему, тут только ручками программисту.

@Arbery ну, я понимаю масштаб всей это работы. Но CSS считает же. На любом устройстве, любая единица она считает и выдает результат, так? Вот и я использую те же самые методы который использует CSS. Ну а ручками сейчас пытаюсь что-то такое делать)

Желательно всё таки знать величину которая будет root: иначе прийдеться писать функцию определения, а так то вот.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const stringSizeStandard = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--size-standard");
  console.log(stringSizeStandard);


  // Преобразуем значение в число без единицы измерения
  const sizeStandardWithoutUnit = parseInt(stringSizeStandard);

  // Теперь получаем размер в пикселях
  const sizeStandardInPx = sizeStandardWithoutUnit * (window.innerWidth / 100); // Переводим из vw в px

  console.log(sizeStandardInPx + "px");


});
:root {
  --size-standard: 6vmin;
}

.block {
  width: var(--size-standard);
  height: 30px;
  background-color: pink;
}
<div class="block"></div>



Возможно вы пытались получить значения, до момента сборки DOM дерева и отрисовки нужных стилей...

Вот основная проблема именно в том, что мне неизвестно тип единицы. Вот пример у вас в ответе работает, но когда я попробовал у себя (где на этот раз значение было calc(6vmin)), я получил NaN в функции parseInt.

CSSNumericValue.parse() мне нравится тем, что он разбирает не смотря на значение. Но почему то именно когда я хочу переводить полученное значение в px выдает ошибку.

Ну так, это логично. Сбросте результат вычисления в какую-то отдельную переменную. По типу --s2: calc(var(--size-standard) + 50px); и уже считайте её

Честно сказать, не понял последний комментарий. А если единица будет в em тогда как считать?

Вот статья об этом. https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units   Но этих величин такой зоопарк, что не понятно какую именну вы цель приследуете. В любом случаии написание функции конвертация это не то, что спрашиваеться в теме данного вопроса. Можна нагуглить.
